# Why Index is Needed for Rails Model Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, model, associations

I'm a bit confused on the topic of index columns in model associations.

(From the *The Rails 4 Way*) We have `User`, `Timesheet`, and `Expense Report` models.

The `User` model:

```
has_many: timesheets
has_many: expense_reports
```

(along with the corresponding `belongs_to` in the other models)

*The Rails 4 Way* book says to `add_index` into the `timesheets` and `expense_reports` model as so:

```
add_index :timesheets, :user_id
add_index :expense_reports, :user_id
```

I don't understand the reasoning for adding an index after every foreign key column. The `timesheet` and `expense_report` tables already have a `primary_key` column so why isn't that used for "performance boos?" Adding two additional indices seems redundant to me? Can someone explain the benefit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see where your frustration comes from, just follow along and I am sure you'll get it pretty fast...

## **Problem:**

When you create a column in a database, it is vital to consider whether you will need to find and retrieve records from that column. So, lets say we have a **User** table and every user has an **email**, that in many applications is used for authentication and authorization of users. When we allow users to log in to our application, we will need to find the user record corresponding to the submitted email address. **Unfortunately**, the only way to find a user by email address is to scan through each user row in the database and compare its email attribute to the given email - which, therefore, implies we might have to examine every row(since the user can be the last person inside the database). This would take a lot of time as you can imagine. Simply, this is not good.

## **Solution:**

Putting an **index** on the email column would fix the problem. Think of it as an appendix at the end of the book. In a book, to find all the occurrences of a given string, say “foobar”, you would have to scan each page for “foobar” - the paper version of a full-table scan. With a book index, on the other hand, you can just look up “foobar” in the index to see all the pages containing “foobar”. A database index works essentially the same way.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: First thank you so much for the answer, I'm 90% of the way there. My question is now: let's say the client submits _me@myself.com_. The problem I'm seeing is it still needs to scan at least the whole _email_ column to find the right one. So are you saying an index makes it possible to only scan the entire database of one column instead of the full row? Sorry if I'm still not understanding, but initially I don't see how an index would help since the inputted _email_ obviously won't be accompanied with the proper index...

Comment: By creating an index on one or more columns of a table, you gain the ability in some cases to retrieve a small set of randomly distributed rows from the table. Indexes are one of many means of reducing disk I/O. If still in doubt I highly encourage you to check out this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)

Comment: I really appreciate the help, like I said I'm almost there, but I will continue to read.

Comment: It is quite a lot to cram, don't let it intimidate you and you'll get it eventually. All best.